# How to have html popup appear over main html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been making a website-resume and I want the user to be able to click on a picture of a company I've worked for and have a description of my work experience come up. I can click on a picture and have a div pop up on top as shown here:

[image]

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: u r asking how u can make a pop up or wat ? @bsteven ?

Comment: You are expected to make more of an effort than this in formulating a question in this community. Please search for the "how to ask" page for some tips on how to create a question that will be better received.

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to make a popup like this: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/

Comment: its free theme u can modify it and use it

Comment: however if u want to design a pop up urslf i can guide u @bsteven48

Answer (score 0):

you can set css to the popup div which u want to show over the html page.
Consider the following eg:

```css
#mainPage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

#popUp {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ADD;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="mainPage">
    <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300" width="20%" />
  </div>
  <div id="popUp">
    <p>Hello !!! It's a popup div </p>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#mainPage img').on('click', function() {
      $('#popUp').show();
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```